# Extended polynomials in library NTL

Tags: c++, gmp, number-theory, ntl

There is code is written using NTL library:

```
int main()
{
      ZZ_p::init(ZZ(5)); // define GF(5)

      ZZ_pX P;
      BuildIrred(P, 4); // generate an irreducible polynomial P
                         // of degree 4 over GF(5)

      ZZ_pE::init(P); // define GF(5^4)

      ZZ_pEX f, g, h;  // declare polynomials over GF(5^4)

      random(f, 3);  // f is a random, monic polynomial of degree 3
      SetCoeff(f, 3);
      cout << f << endl<< endl;
}
```

The output is:

```
[[3 1 1 4] [2 1 3 2] [1 0 3 1] [1]]
```

For example, `[1 2 3]` is mean `3x² + 2x + 1`.
What the form of notation polynomial over GF in this case?

Comment: This is C++, not C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little bit difficult to understand. If I understand you right, the question is how to interpret the NTL representation `[[3 1 1 4] [2 1 3 2] [1 0 3 1] [1]]` of a polynomial over the finite field with 5⁴ elements.

First: The elements in the finite field with 5⁴ elements (called `GF(5⁴)`) are represented as the polynomials `GF(5)[X] mod f`, where `f` is an irreducible polynomial of degree 4.

This means a polynomial over `GF(5⁴)` is a Polynomial where the coefficients are polynomials in `GF(5)[X] mod f`.

So `[[3 1 1 4] [2 1 3 2] [1 0 3 1] [1]]` can be interpreted as

```
Y³ + (X³ + 3X² + 1)⋅Y² + (2X³ + 3X² + X + 2)⋅Y + (4X³ + X² + X + 3)
```

Notice: The comment in

```
random(f, 3);  // f is a random, monic polynomial of degree 3
SetCoeff(f, 3);
```

is a little bit misleading. `random(f,3)` sets `f` to a random polynomial of degree *less than* 3. `SetCoeff(f, 3)` sets the coefficient of `Y³` to `1` and after that it is a polynomial of degree 3.

Comment: yes, how to interpret the NTL representation :) thanks